# javascript set className property for Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, classname

I set className property of a dinamically generated select control with the following code:

```
oField.className ="select";
```

It works for Firefox not for Internet Explorer. How can I set this property on IE?

The code:

```
var oField = document.createElement("select");  
if(browser == "IE"){  
    oField.size = 1;  
    oField.setAttribute("name","sele"+num); 
    oField.onChange = function(){
        AggiungiRiga(oField.name,oField.value)
    };
}  
else{  
   oField.setAttribute("size",1);
   oField.setAttribute("name","sele"+num);
   oField.setAttribute("onChange","AggiungiRiga(this.name,this.value)");
}  
oField.className ="select";
```

Here I add it to the document:

```
oTd1.appendChild(oField);
```

(`oTd1` is the `<td>` element where the select control must be place). I know the code is not of good quality cause is legacy code.

Comment: Assuming that `oField` is an HTMLElementNode, that should work just fine in IE. Your problem likely lies elsewhere.

Comment: oField is just a variable. I set id, name, value, className and then I add it at the document.

Comment: Show the code that sets "oField" to a value.

Comment: And the code that adds it to the document.

Comment: You should not be using "setAttribute()" for any of the things you're doing in that code.

Comment: oTd1 is null or not not an object

Answer (score 0):

I see no `appendChild()` method, where are you appending the `select element`?

not appending the `oField` to the document could be causing you issues.

eg:

```
document.body.appendChild(oField);
```

Also where are the variables `browser` and `num` declared from? i guess if its working in FF num is declared.

```
 var oField = document.createElement("select");

 oField.size = 1;
 oField.name = "sele" + num; 

 oField.onChange = function(){AggiungiRiga(oField.name,oField.value)};

 oField.className = "select";

 document.getElementById('tabella').getElementsByTagName('TBODY')[0].childNodes[0].firstChild.appendChild(oField)
```

Do you know what would of made it easy i had a `id` for the `TD` and it worked, i would be easer if you had a `TD id=""` any way if you wanted the select to be placed in the first TD this will do it compleate example shown above

```
   document.getElementById('tabella').getElementsByTagName('TBODY')[0].childNodes[0].firstChild.appendChild(oField)
```

you would however need to have the table as compact

```
<table id="tabella"><tr><td></td></tr></table>
```

Comment: @AntonioF looking at you code you do not need to check if(browser == "IE"), because just appending onchange will be ok, ive update my answer

Comment: oTd1 is <td> object that is appended to oTr (a <tr> object) that is appended to a table by:
document.getElementById('tabella').getElementsByTagName('TBODY')[0].appendChild(oTr);

Answer (score -6):

Why don't you  try do it with jquery:

```
$('#idElement').attr('class', 'classname');
```

Or just with javascript :

```
document.getElementById("idElement").setAttribute("class", "className");
```

Comment: There's no reason to use "setAttribute()" to set the "className" property of a real DOM element.

Comment: `setAttribute` is broken in (not much) older versions of IE, in particular if you try to set the `class` attribute then it will try to set the `class` *property* and not the `className` property, so this won't work.

Comment: If I put aside my general dislike of "run to jQuery for the most trivial problem" answers, then if you *are* going to use jQuery to twiddle with class names, then it has `addClass` and friends so using `attr` is generally a poor choice for that task.